# Have Jmeter use different Certs from keystore to make to requests

Tags: ssl, https, jmeter

Need help setting up Jmeter to use multiple Certs.
Need Jmeter HTTPS requests to use different client certificates that I have in a JKS keystore, currently 2 client certs/keys are in it.

Currently I have few HTTPS request in first thread group which should be made using CERT1 and Second thread group has few more HTTPS request which should be made using CERT2.

I am using KeyStore configuration to have have these different thread groups to use different CERTs by using alias or index.

Besides adding the Keystore Configuration to the thread group and setting different alias to select different Cert, Jmeter is not using different certs to make request. I see the same cert is being used.

I have set -Jhttps.use.cached.ssl.context=false -Jhttps.socket.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%KEYSTORE% -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=%KEY_PASS%

and also I am using HTTPClient4 in my HTTPS requests.

Is there something that I am missing..any help would be appropriated..?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation reference:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration

Pay attention to the yellow notes:

> To make JMeter use more than one certificate you need to ensure that:
>   - https.use.cached.ssl.context=false is set in jmeter.properties or user.properties
>   - You use either HTTPClient 3.1 or 4 implementations for HTTP Request

Comment: Thanks, however that has already been done.

Please pay attention to my question:
I have set -Jhttps.use.cached.ssl.context=false -Jhttps.socket.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%KEYSTORE% -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=%KEY_PASS%
and also I am using HTTPClient4 in my HTTPS requests.

Comment: can you show your test plan zooming on keystore config and csv ? also use user.properties instead of -J